# Retreive layers from MLPRegressor

Tags: scikit-learn, neural-network

Is it possible to extract all the layers from an object of the class sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor once trained, to used them in another situation ?

The class has a function get_params that only returns the parameters but not the layers matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out on my own, the MLPRegressor class has an attribute coefs_ that can be retreived.